# graphcool: command not found (locally on Mac)

Tags: graphcool

I am installing graphcool locally on my Mac which I think has gone ok:

```
$ sudo npm install -g graphcool
npm WARN deprecated jsonstream@1.0.3: use JSONStream instead
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
/usr/local/bin/graphcool-framework -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphcool/dist/index.js
/usr/local/bin/gcf -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphcool/dist/index.js
+ graphcool@0.11.4
updated 1 package in 7.251s
```

But the graphcool doesn't seem to be recognized:

```
$ graphcool init server
-bash: graphcool: command not found
```

I get the same error from `graphcool init`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: with the latest Framework version, the CLI binary [was renamed to graphcool-framework](https://github.com/graphcool/framework/releases/tag/0.11.4). graphcool is now used for the preview of the Graphcool 1.0 CLI. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like they changed the binary name from `graphcool` to `graphcool-framework` and `gcf`

https://github.com/graphcool/framework/commit/5de2334440c55f6a42f6d75ad1b06a8d320d5e40

Try:

```
graphcool-framework init
```

If you get an error saying "no such file or directory, lstat '~/.graphcool'", do

```
touch ~/.graphcool
```

Then retype the init command above

Answer (score 0):

The order in which I set up graphcool was:

```
npm install -g graphcool-framework
mkdir ~/.graphcool
cd .graphcool
touch config.yml
graphcool-framework init server
```